# Zebra EMDK plugin for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, motorola-emdk

After install Android Studio 2.3.1 and Zebra EMDK 6.3, Android Studio show this exception when i clic the menu EMDK -> Profile manager:

> null  java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   com.intellij.ide.SystemHealthMonitor.getActionName(SystemHealthMonitor.java:542)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.SystemHealthMonitor.countActionInvocation(SystemHealthMonitor.java:479)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.fireBeforeActionPerformed(ActionManagerImpl.java:1190)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$2(ActionMenuItem.java:292)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:905)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:284)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$300(TransactionGuardImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:123)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:109)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:627)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

I have:

- Windows 7 x64
- Android Studio 2.3.1
- Zebra EMDK 6.3 (https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/emdk-for-android.html)

And need this to develope an app for Zebra TC8000. Some idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

The current version of EMDK For Android 6.x does not work when Android Studio is upgraded to 2.3.1. You need to download a patch, copy the jars to EMDK Integrator path and run the EMDK Integrator. This resolves the issue.

The patch file and instructions are available in https://developer.zebra.com/community/android/android-forums/android-blogs/blog/2017/03/15/android-studio-23-emdk-for-android-beta-fix

Comment: DrThis was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.